# Using custom prettifying code inside a SO post

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

In my Stack Overflow activity, I'm mostly interested in HPC and parallel programming, notably with [openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openmp) and [mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpi). Both of them support [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) as targeted languages, so I have quite often the opportunity to post Fortran code snippets in answers. But since unfortunately, Fortran isn't officially supported by [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), these snippets are just very grim and not too nice to read (see [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136371/covariance-calculation-with-a-nested-loop-in-openmp/33140528#33140528)).

That said, it turns out that [somebody wrote the code needed](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=78) for supporting Fortran with Google Code Prettify, but this apparently never landed into the official package (the code itself is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=78#c4)).

So my question is as follow: assuming this prettifying works (which I never tried) but never lands anywhere inside the official SO sources (which is likely since it didn't make it for the Google distribution), is there a way of manually including it inside a Fortran-related SO post so that codes are prettified?

My feeling is that since JavaScript code snippets can be inserted / executed inside SO posts, this might be feasible... But that said, I have exactly zero competence in JavaScript or anything related to web development, so I truly don't know if my question makes any sense at all.